# Excel 2013 VBA Runtime Error 5 with listobjects.add

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error, listobject

I have a main sub that I am using to set up my worksheets and data for analysis in other subroutines. As part of this I am turning some imported data into a table(data was imported from a CSV file) and placed into "IncidentsData" worksheet. The code for the entire module compiles. However, when I step through the module I get "Run-Time Error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument" on the line where I format the imported data into a table at:

```
Worksheets("IncidentsData").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ISDRange, , xlYes).Name   = "IncidentsDataTable"
```

Here is the overall subroutine:

```
Public Sub Categorise_Incidents()
Dim incidentsData1 As ListObject
Set Commodity = Worksheets("CommoditySheet").ListObjects("Table1")
Set QEListByGenus = Worksheets("QEListByGenus")
Set Results = Worksheets("Results")
Set IncidentsDataSheet = Worksheets("IncidentsData")
ISDRange = IncidentsDataSheet.UsedRange
Worksheets("IncidentsData").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ISDRange, , xlYes).Name   = "IncidentsDataTable"
Set incidentsData1 = IncidentsDataSheet.ListObjects("IncidentsDataTable")
initialiseDictionaries
MainSearchLoop QEListByGenus, incidentsData1, dictQENSGenus
End Sub
```

I have gone to a number of sites to work out how to do this action including: 
1. the stack overflow pages on runtime error 5 in excel vba - most of these seem to be specific to pivot tables and didn't tell me what I was doing wrong
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/listobjects-object-excel
3. stack overflow questions on creating a table in VBA [How to create a table using vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010246/how-to-create-a-table-using-vba)
4. analysistabs on creating a table in excel vba
https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/tables-examples/
Plus a bunch of others. Unfortunately, they haven't helped me work out what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Cheers, S26

Edited: to include .Name as that also does not work and throws a runtime error and to fix typos/errors.

Comment: You added the `.Name` on the wrong line.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I know. It still doesn't work and throws the same error even though syntax appears to be correct  now and I've removed the typos. (don't code late at night should be the moral of that story)

Comment: `Dim ISDRange as Range` and then `Set ISDRange  = ...`

Comment: @BigBen, thanks! I really appreciate your help. That solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change `xlSrcERange` and `lYes` to `xlSrcRange` and `xlYes`.

You're missing the `.Name` at the end of `Worksheets("IncidentsData").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ISDRange, , xlYes)`. You haven't specified which property of the newly created table you want to be `"IncidentsDataTable"`.

Alternately, you can do this:

```
Set incidentsData1 = Worksheets("IncidentsData").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ISDRange, , xlYes)
incidentsData1.Name = "IncidentsDataTable"
```

If you take that approach, it looks like you don't need to change the `Name` at all.

Comment: thanks very much for pointing that out. I had already tried that format with '.Name' and ended up playing around with it as I couldn't get it to work, Unfortunately, neither does your second solution. Even though I know theoretically both should work, it still throws a runtime error5, which is weird. Do you have any idea why it would do that?

Comment: That should be `xlSrcRange` and `xlYes` maybe? Edited.

Comment: Dim ISDRange as Range and then Set ISDRange = ... – BigBen 14 mins ago

Comment: Moral of the story is don't answer questions at night either. And use `Option Explicit`.